# Differences between PC and PS4 updates?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I can't find an overview of the GTA V Online Content Updates.  Are all PC updates available for PS4, or is there some exclusive PC content?

I'm a huge fan, so I want to make sure I won't miss any updates if I buy the game for PS4 instead of PC. (I already own the game for PS3)

Comment: please leave a comment before downvoting ... the question is very legitimate and nobody seems to have an answer, so it is definetely not a duplicate or anything similar

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple answer.
Update support has stopped for PS3 and XBox 360 (system memory can't keep up anymore).

Update support is active on: PS4, XBone, PC. These platforms will receive the same updates.

Example: The lowrider version of the tornado comes out on PS4, XBox One and PC today. However, it will not be released on PS3 and XBox 360 due to memory limitations.

edit: No, doesn't matter if you buy the PS4, XBox One, or PC version. You won't miss out on anything.

Second edit: [Source](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52429/asked-answered-the-rockstar-editor-gta-online-updates)

They state the following:

> We want to support the older consoles with new content for as long as we possibly can. As we mentioned previously, we always knew there might be a point where we would reach the technical capacity of what the older generation of consoles can handle as each downloadable update requires additional memory both for assets and for additional scripting.  We have continued to optimize the entire game over time in order to squeeze as much memory as we possibly could out of the last-generation hardware and at some point, continuing to add content for those systems could cause the risk of instability to the game overall. As of now, we are planning on releasing the next big content update for all five systems and we will continue to squeeze as much as we possibly can onto them.

One last example: The tornado DLC (lowrider) is available on Ps4, Xbox one, and PC. With no differences between these systems. However on ps3 and xbox 360, The tornado DLC will not be available, because (as stated above) the systems just cant keep up. (to old)

Comment: I also think, that this is the way things work, but can you give some proove to this answer ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you mean DLC, as the updates tend to be more bug fixes and will vary from system to system.

I have read a few articles and webpages about GTA V's DLC, mainly [this](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/DLC).  And by what I have read, all DLC will be available on the XBOX One, PS4, and PC.

You seem to be referencing the *Content Updates*.  According to the [GTA V wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V#Downloadable_Content), DLC is part of those updates.  The *Content Update* is the update with the content that allows the DLC (if not free) to be purchased. If the DLC is free, the content update is the DLC.

Comment: have a look at the following page: http://www.rockstargames.com/V/GTAOnline/content ... they are called updates in this context ;)

Comment: @user2664856 those are "Content Updates" not "Updates". Also in the GTA5 wiki, http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V#Downloadable_Content, it says that the DLC is part of the content update.  The content update is the update that allows the DLC (if not free) to be purchased.  If the DLC is free, the content update is the DLC.

Comment: Feel free to edit my post, if you find it to be missleading ;)

Comment: @user2664856 do you own the game for PC yet?

Comment: no, i have it for PS3, like stated in the question